# Is it possible to enforce prettier style as tslint rule?

Tags: typescript, tslint, prettier

As we can have command line lint tools that show if a code is linked, is there something else for prettier, maybe it can integrate with tslint and tslint could show errors if the code is not formatted?

Comment: This *might* be along the lines of what you want. https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-config-prettier It makes sure that tslint and prettier cooperate with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [tslint-plugin-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/tslint-plugin-prettier) which will report prettier differences as tslint issues.

as mentioned in the [readme](https://github.com/prettier/tslint-plugin-prettier#usage) you should also use [tslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/tslint-config-prettier) to avoid conflicts between prettier rules and tslint rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the various TS Lint formatting rules, eg https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/indent/, so if the code isn't formatted you'll get a warning. Once you've worked out your set of rules you need, it should give you warnings.

Alternatively, why not just add commit hooks to format the code before it is pushed?